# Django: how to do this query?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models:

- a model `Product` that is linked with a ManyToMany `Tag` model
- a model `Tag` that is linked with a ManyToMany `Product` model
- a model `TagContent` that is linked with a OneToMany `Tag` model (= one content is linked to only one `Tag` and one `Tag` may have one or more `TagContent`)

The model `TagContent` is for multilanguage: one `Product` may have many `Tag`, but those `Tag` show up in the Web page through `TagContent`:

```
class Tag(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True, default='')

class TagContent(BaseTranslatableModel):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=True, default=None)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    locale = models.CharField(max_length=2)  # (e.g. "fr")

class Produit(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='produits')
```

Here's what I want to do: in my main page, the customer choose the language. Thus I will display all the products based on the language the customer has chosen.

In my main view, I want to display all the products, and all the tags so the user can click on a tag, and i'll filter the product.

The problem is that the tag should be translated in the current language. This means I have to filter the `TagContent` with the current locale, then get all `Tag` that are linked to those `TagContent` then get all the `Product` that are linked to those tags.

This should give something like (but it doesn't work because the foreign key is in the `TagContent`, and this is the main problem that blocks me):

```
Product.objects.filter(tags__in=
    Tag.objects.filter(contents__in=
        TagContent.objects.filter(langue__locale__exact=locale)
    )
)
```

And in the templating model I need something like:

```
        {% for p in products %}
            {% for tag. in p.tags.all %}
                {{ tag.name }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

In other words, I'd like to do this SQL query:

```
 SELECT tc.slug, tc.name
 FROM produit p
 JOIN produit_tag pt
     ON pt.produit_id = p.id
 JOIN tag t
     ON pt.tag_id = t.id
 JOIN tag_content tc
     ON tc.tag_id = t.id
 JOIN langue l
     ON tc.langue_id=l.id
 WHERE l.locale='fr'
```

-> 2 minutes to write this SQL, 3 hours that I'm looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this orm query to get the products:

```
products = Product.objects.prefetch_related("Tag", "TagContent").
    filter(tags__tagcontent__locale="fr")
```

Django will produce a SQL just like your hand written one. However, multiple JOINs within one SQL is perhaps not a good idea, especially if the joined tables are quite large. Consider breaking the query into 2 might result in better performance (depends on the DB you are using):

```
fr_tags = Tag.objects.filter(tagcontent__locale="fr")
products = Product.objects.filter(tags__in=fr_tags)
```

Read about Field lookup that spans relationships:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the SQL query, why don't you just send a [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/) instead. And you can just pass the data into your template. It would be something similar to this:

```
from django.db import connections

cursor = connection.cursor()
query = (""" SELECT tc.slug, tc.name
 FROM produit p
 JOIN produit_tag pt
     ON pt.produit_id = p.id
 JOIN tag t
     ON pt.tag_id = t.id
 JOIN tag_content tc
     ON tc.tag_id = t.id
 JOIN langue l
     ON tc.langue_id=l.id
 WHERE l.locale='fr' """)
cursor.execute(query)

data = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    slug = row[0]
    name = row[1]
    data_point = {'name': name, 'slug': slug}
    data.append(data_point)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using PostgreSQL this is useless to you, but my former lead developer now maintains the [django-pgviews](https://github.com/mypebble/django-pgviews/tree/master/django_pgviews) project. It's useful when you have SQL queries containing complex joins that Django might not be able to do efficiently (or at all), which you can represent in a custom SQL View. You sacrifice Django's management, but you can keep using the ORM to query data for reading. Note also the django.contrib.postgres project that is in development.